# How to stock data in the specific place of flash memory stm32 and keil?

Tags: stm32, keil

I wanna store some variable in specific place of FLASH memory on stm32, so i changed the scatter file in keil. but anytime i checked the map file, the variable doesn't in the true place in Flash memory.
my scatter file:

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00007800  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00007800  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  user_flash 0x08007800 0x00000800  { 
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00001000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

and my variable:

```
__IO float  EE_Myvariable __attribute__((section(".user_flash"))) = 21.0;
```

how can i cope with this issue?
thanks in advance

Comment: KEEP is your friend

Comment: I Changed the scatter file to : `My_flash 0x08007800 0x00000800  { 
   *.o(.user_flash)
  }`, when I checked the map file ,The EE_Myvariable was in 0x08007800. but when i tried to program and check with stm32, it stayed in `void HardFault_Handler(void)` function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chenged to this:

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00007800  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00007800  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00001000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
LR_IROM2 0x08007800 0x00000800 {
  My_flash 0x08007800 0x00000800  {  ; load address = execution address
    ;.ANY (+RW)
    *.o(.user_flash)
  }
}
```

and that worked truly